# How do I add a search box in my Google Maps for local restaurants?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-places-api

quick summary of my project. I'm building a table reservation application, now, I've got Google Maps working, but it looks like this.

[image]

**The single marker is intentional.**

That's the location of a special restaurant that I will use during my presentation, so naturally, it's meant to stay there.

However, you will also notice that there is obviously no search bar. Whenever I try to place the initAutoComplete function into the maps, my whole map disappears. What am I doing wrong? Here is my current code (that I have up to date that does NOT break the maps).

**HTML**

```
<div id="map-container">
    <div id="map">
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function renderRestaurantInfo(restaurant){
  return (
    "<h2>"+restaurant.title+"</h2>" +
    "<a href='/reservations/index'>Make a Reservation</a>"
  );  
}

function addMarkerToMap(restaurant,map){
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: restaurant.lat, lng: restaurant.lng},
    map: map,
    title: restaurant.title
  }); 

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: renderRestaurantInfo(restaurant)
  }); 

  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }); 
}

function initMap(){
    var initialLocation = {lat: 39.9522334, lng: -75.1694917 };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: initialLocation,
        zoom: 15
    }); 

    var restaurant = { 
        title: 'My Restaurant',
        lat: 39.9522334,
        lng: -75.1694917
    }
    addMarkerToMap(restaurant,map);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for / thinking of is the "places search box":
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

That link above should really help.